# Referring to the 'new' points of a compactification

Tags: general-topology, terminology, compactification

Given a topological space $X$ and a compactification $\alpha X$ of it, I want to refer to the points of $\alpha X-X$.
Here is my problem: Since I want to do this in an abstract, and since here I always write 'foo compactification' instead of $\alpha X$, I would like to refer to the points of $\alpha X-X$ via a simple phrase or just a word, e.g. 'compactification points' or 'points at infinity'.
Now 'compactification points' can easily be misunderstood to mean the points of $\alpha X$, whereas 'points at infinity' sounds a bit sloppy.

In Engelking's and Willard's books on topology I did not find a name for the points of $\alpha X-X$, and my online research kept showing me general questions about the one-point and the Stone-Cech compactification.

Do you know a name/really short phrase for the points of $\alpha X-X$ that is accepted in the field, or can you say that there is no commonly known such name?

If there is no such name, of course I can work around it by naming the 'foo compactification', but being unable to find an answer to this simple question by myself made me curious.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe "ideal points"? Not sure if that's widely used.

Comment: @chris I never heard of it, but it seems to be clear to folks familiar with geometry. My target audience is familiar with graph-theory, where 'points at infinity' usually mean 'ends'. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's standardly called "the remainder". For the particular case of the Cech-Stone compactification $X^\ast$ is used for $\beta X\setminus X$.
So just say the remainder of $X$ to refer to the new points. Point(s) at infinity is used for the one-point compactification, or the (linear) two-point compactification.